# How can I use part of an array value as key for a new array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I loop through an array and use part of the value as key for a new array?

Something like this:

```
$I = glob("path/to/file/*.txt");
foreach($I as $i){
    //key = function_acting_on($i) | value = $i
}
```

---

For example, when I do this:

```
$I = glob("path/to/file/*.txt");
foreach($I as $i){
    $new_array[] = $i;
}
```

This would automatically use numerical enumerated keys. But in my code I want to use part of the value `$i` as key.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "world"
}
```

---

I used the accepted answer in the following way:

```
$images = glob("images/*.txt");
foreach( $images as $image ){
    preg_match('$pattern',$image,$match);
    $value = (int)preg_replace($pattern_,'',$match[0]);
    $array[$value] = $image;
    }
ksort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Noticing now that duplicate keys are suppressed.

Comment: Hey again stack xD And can I ask what exactly you mean as a `key` and `value` ?

Comment: Do you mean `foreach ($Item as $key => $value) {...}`?

Comment: No that would be if I wanted the key and value for each `$i` in my array `$I`. In this case I only want the _values_ in `$I`, and then I want to make a new array from this with the key being an integer contained in `$i` and the value being `$i`, does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, got it. Try this: `foreach ($I as $i) {$array[someFunc($i)] = $i;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote in the comments, if you want to use a particular value as key of your array for a new array, you can simply do it like this:

```
$I = glob("path/to/file/*.txt");
$newArray = [];
foreach($I as $i){
    if(isset($newArray[function_acting_on($i)])){
        if(!is_array($newArray[function_acting_on($i)]))
            $newArray[function_acting_on($i)] = [$newArray[function_acting_on($i)]];
        $newArray[function_acting_on($i)][] = $i;
    } else {
    $newArray[function_acting_on($i)] = $i; 
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Just use the return value as key
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I avoid duplicate key suppression? That is, say I have two keys that are the same...

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Depends on what you want to do if you encounter one

Comment: Well, say I have `'22'=>'jdfhgjfd-p.txt'` and `'22'=>'jdfhgjfd-q.txt'` and I want to keep them and store them in the array sorted as they are shown above.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Well do you want to store it as subArrays if you got multiple same keys or want to use a prefix number?

Comment: How would `ksort` handle a "prefix number"? Wouldn't a postfix decimal  be better? Like 22.1 and 22.2, that way `21=>bla`, `22.1=>bla`, `22.1=>bla`, `23=>bla` would be handled correctly by ksort, and all I'd have to change is the data type casting from `(int)` to `(double)`.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth I never said anything about `ksort()`. And that is my question what do you want if you encounter multiple same keys? Want to do this: `22-1`, `22-2` or `22 => [valueOne, valueTwo]`?

Comment: Can you do 22.1 and 22.2, or would 22-1 and 22-2 sort just the same; I guess they would...

Comment: @stackoverfloweth You can, but I would use a subArray, e.g. `22 => [your vaues]`. It will make handling the values easier. As I said depends on what you want/need I can update my answer and show how you can do it.

Comment: The array containing these key-value pairs will eventually be put in a `foreach` loop and I'll be manipulating the _values_, so what would be best? Having an array in an array among strings seems like a hiccup in my `foreach` loop.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth I would use a subArray, then you can just check with an if statement if you got a subArray: `is_array($value)`. Just updated the answer. So if you have 2x key `22` you get: `22 => [1, 2]`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Are you sure you wrote it right?

Comment: @stackoverfloweth I had a typo in it, which I already fixed. You might copied it before it. Just try it again

Comment: I copied after you fixed the typo, and the `var_dump` shows no array within array. I think I see how to fix the problem though.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Dumb error on my side. I wrote the code correctly, but the code after the if statement just undid what we did in the if statement, so just put it into an else statement.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. Thank you.